# Efficiently uploading a large git repository to Github

Tags: git, performance, github, upload

I'm working on a large Git repository with several gigabytes of data. When I attempt to push the repository to GitHub using the git push command, it takes an extremely long time, often causing timeouts and errors. I'm wondering if there are any more efficient methods for uploading large Git repositories to GitHub without encountering these issues.

The local repository size is approximately 5GB.
The GitHub repository is newly created and empty.
The network connection is stable and has sufficient bandwidth.
Possible solutions:

Splitting the repository into smaller chunks and pushing them individually.
Using Git LFS (Large File Storage) to manage large files within the repository.
Utilizing GitHub's command-line tools for optimizing the upload process.
Additional considerations:

Minimizing the number of network requests during the upload process.
Ensuring the upload process is reliable and avoids timeouts or errors.
I'm eager to hear from experienced Git users about their recommendations for effectively uploading large repositories to GitHub. Any insights or tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: May I ask what's responsible for the huge size? What file types? Can these files be stored on a database instead?